# Passing variant parameters by name from external program not possible in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried to call Excel-specific VBA functions from an external program.  Unfortunately, I have not found any way to pass variant parameters by name.

Here's an example to illustrate the problem:
Let's say I have opened a word document and an excel file. Using a macro in the word document, I  want to find an entry in my excel file and save the corresponding cell for later use.

```
Sub Main()

 Dim FoundCell As Object
 Set ExcelWs = GetObject(, "Excel.Application").Worksheets("Table1")

 Set FoundCell = ExcelWs.Range("A1", "D4").Find(What:="findMe", lookat:=xlwhole)

End Sub
```

When I try to run this, the parameter for lookat throws an error because xlwhole is not recognized.

My ideas so far:

1. Leaving lookat:=xlwhole out makes the code run, but it is not an option because I need to find an exact match.
2. Adding an equivalent macro to the excel file is not an option because the file is protected.

Comment: If you're late bound, constants and enumerations like `xlwhole` aren't available at compile time, so they default to undeclared variables. You need to either pass the numeric value or define them in the calling code.

Comment: `?xlwhole` in the Excel VBA immediate window evaluate evaluates to `1`, showing that you can just use `1` for `xlwhole` (doing such an experiment is often easier than finding the documentation).

Comment: Thanks, setting xlwhole=1 seems to make it work, that's a compromise I can work with.

Comment: Make sure `Option Explicit` is at the top of every module (there's a setting for that in the VBE options - "require variable declaration"), and declare every variable.